# Input validation in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am struggling to come up with a clean way to do input validation in Elixir.

In a OOP language i would do something like this:

```
def my_func(a, b):
  if !validate_a(a):
    raise ArgumentError
  if !validate_b(b):
    raise ArgumentError
  return "something"
```

The best i could come up with in Elixir is this:

```
def my_func(a, b) do
  cond do
    not valid_a?(a) -> {:error, "a is invalid"}
    not valid_b?(b) -> {:error, "b is invalid"}
    :otherwise      -> {:ok, "something"}
  end
end
```

I know that i could also raise an exception in Elxir, but i like pattern-matching against the return type a lot better, since my code doesn't get cluttered with try/rescue blocks.

Is there a preferred pattern to do this in Elixir?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Instead of `:otherwise ->` for the last case, I've seen most people use `true ->`.

Comment: I've seen that too. Personally i prefer `:else` or `:otherwise` for readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything depends what comes **after** the validation and what **kind** of validation you want to have.

For example: if you simply validate is `a` and `b` are integers you can use `guard` clauses in definitions of the functions.

```
def my_func(a, b) when is_integer(a) and is_integer(b) do
  # your code - validation passed
end

def my_func(_, _) do
  # validation failed
end
```

In terms of custom validation is good to have separate function and you can use it in your "main" function - your code is cleaner and easier to test, since it's better isolated. In your case - this `cond` with validation might be in different function.

When dealing with validation in Phoenix controllers you can obviously create own [Plugs](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.html#content), which is really handy when you can use like `before` in Ruby on Rails controllers.

Comment: Can you give an example on how you would factor out my `cond` block into a different function?

Comment: In this case: simply rename it to `validate` and in `my_func` I would call validate at the top.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the complexity of your validations and what your data looks like, you could also opt to use [`Ecto.Changeset`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html) even if you do not plan to store the data.

Something really simple like the following

```
defmodule Foo do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "my_schema" do
    field :name, :string
    field :age, :integer
  end

  def changeset(struct, params) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name, :age])
    |> validate_required([:name, :age])
    |> validate_number(:age, greater_than: 18)
  end
end
```

Once you run the `changeset/2` function, you will be given an `Ecto.Changeset` as a result which has a `valid?` field. If this is true, it passed all of your validations. If it is false, it will also tell you why from the `:errors` key from the changeset.